# How to initialize a variable value

Tags: angular

Let’s assume a scenario. We have a list of musicians (coming from an API service call in JSON format)who can play different genres of music
Now I’m supposed to display these Genres along side the name of the musician.

There is a small requirement . We can only display 3 genres next to the name. If the musician can play more than 3 genres the names should be displayed somewhere else, maybe a pop up for more info. How can I keep a count of this no of genres for a particular musician, so that if the genres more then 3 then only I need to display the others in ye pop up.

Until now 1.div id musicians  for let x of musicians
..........
2. div  {x,musicianName}
3.div Genres 
span ngIf x,genreMetal Metal
4.span ngIf x,genreClassical Classical
5.span ngIf x,genreIndie Indie 
6.span ngIf x,genreMetal & x,genreClassical & x,genreIndie & x,genreRock ..(This is to depict that there are more genres to this musician

Until now hardcoding is what I was doing. I want to make this dynamic. My approach was to use nginit and make a count using interpolation as the values of these genres are coming as 1 and 0. But it’s not happening as there must be something that I may be doing wrong.

Please help..

Comment: Show us what you have already tried, we aren't here to code for you !

Comment: We need details on what you have so far.

Comment: I suppose you should hold all musican's genres as array. In view template you would show only 3 and you would can show genres count.

Comment: Yes @grzesiek I’m trying to imply this. The problem is now these genres are coming from a json and it belongs to an individual musician. In the HTML code I don’t have that much flexibility such as to create a new array where I can keep the list of genres and display them according to the condition. Here is the part where i’m Stuck

Answer (score 1):

With the information you provided, and assuming the array of genres is called "genres", the number of genres would be "artist.genres.length".

Then to display only the first three, you may want to display "artist.genres.slice(0,2)" and then the rest would go in "artist.genres.slice(3, artist.genres.length - 1)"

Finally do one thing or another based on the condition "artist.genres.length > 3"

--------------- Edit based on original question edits --------------

If you are just trying to figure out whether there are three or more genres in that json, what if you do:

```
countGenres(artist) {
   let c=0;
   for(let prop of artist) {
      if(prop.startsWith('genre')) c++;
   }
   return c;
}
```

That would basically count all the genres an artist has, based on the assumption that the properties for each genre starts with the word "genre".

Then ngIf on a span for that function to display either less than three or more than three.

Comment: The artist.genre is not a list of genres that a length function can be used.

Comment: so what is the data type of artist.genre? if it isn't an array... is it something you can do "split()" on? e.g. a comma separated list of genres?

In that case do:
artist.genre = artist.genre.split(',') 

and voilà, now artist genre is indeed something with a .length attribute

Comment: Yes I indeed got your point. But let’s don’t categorise that the list of genres are under one particular key. Just imagine that the genres are coming in this way in the json. Isclassical:1, is rock:0, isindie:1 etc etc. so I was showing these genres by writing an if statement in the ui side.

Comment: Edited the answer with another approach